# How to discover which image file is the current desktop background on Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, desktop-background

It is possible to discover it programatically? It will use the Windows Registry? I'll need to take a screenshot of it and compare with the files on disk? Is it possible to discover even in the desktop slideshow mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string GetCurrentWallpaper()
{
    using(var subKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General", false))
    {
        return subKey.GetValue("WallpaperSource").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on windows 10. This just works if the image came from IE, and stores the last image that came from IE.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

private string GetCurrentWallpaper()

{
 using(RegistryKey MyWallPaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false))
 {
     return MyWallPaper.GetValue("WallPaper").ToString();
 }
}
```

Bye.

Comment: This doesn't work in windows 10 consistently. No such key

Answer (score 0):

The registry key is `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper`

Comment: actually, in Windows 7, it points to a version of the original file "%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg" not the file itself. I think that it's trickier to find the original file in Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SystemParametersInfo() there is a [tutorial on Geekpedia](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial209_Setting-and-Retrieving-the-Desktop-Wallpaper.html) with more information on how to accomplish this with the different Windows OS's and systems.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, and the link doesn't have anything at it.