# How to programatically discover which image file is the current desktop background on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

I just looked at this answer [How to discover which image file is the current desktop background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490202/how-to-discover-which-image-file-is-the-current-desktop-background-on-windows)

And it doesn't answer for windows 10, specifically if the user has chosen a slideshow. How do I determine what's going on?

In Win10 bash would be great, but powershell or C# would work too.

Comment: Use the IDesktopWallpaper interface. It handles the case where the user put a different wallpaper on each monitor.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the slideshow images by using the Windows API. There's a Windows Shell interface called IDesktopWallpaper that has a [GetSlideshow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706954(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

> #### GetSlideshow
>
> Gets the images that are being displayed in the desktop wallpaper slideshow.

If you're using for example C#, it's relatively easy to call this method from managed code using P/Invoke.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, windows background image is always saved to the following directory:

'C:/Users/(Username)/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/CachedFiles/CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg'

If you are using python you can use the os module to get your pc's username by:

```
import os
print(os.getlogin())
```

With it in hand you can then open the background image using:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
dgpath= f'C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/CachedFiles/CachedImage_1366_768_POS4.jpg'
im = Image.open(dgpath) 
im.show()
```

Comment: While this may work under some circumstances, this doesn't appear to work in the case of some slideshows. I do not have a `CachedFiles` folder in my `Themes` folder.